# IIS 7.0 dilemma Chart Control needs an HTTP Handler but using HTTP handler gives it will error 500.23

Tags: iis-7

I have a developed a website with Charts in it. On deploying I found that it gives internal server error 500.23. I removed the section in web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

the site worked but the pages with the Charts stopped working. Exception shown is
"Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd."

As suggested in few other post I have already checked the  section the  are configured as

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
    path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</handlers>
```

Kindly help me and inform me what am I doing wrong?